# How to seperate list elements if key is not present using scala?

Tags: list, scala

```
List((1070071808,"NA",1077477376), (1070071808,aggr1,1077477376), 
(1070071808,aggr1,1077477376), (1070071808,aggr1,1077477376), 
(1070071808,aggr1,1077477376),  (1070071808,aggr1,1077477376),
(1070071808,aggr1,1077477376), (1070071808,aggr1,1077477376))
```

I want addition of usedBytes if second element is not "NA".
My expected output is like

usedSpace = sum of first values from all list elements where second values not equals to "NA"

freeSpace = sum of first values from list if second value is "NA".

How do I get these by using idiomatic scala function??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
val list = List((1070071808, "NA", 1077477376), (1070071808, "aggr1", 1077477376),
  (1070071808, "aggr1", 1077477376), (1070071808, "aggr1", 1077477376),
  (1070071808, "aggr1", 1077477376), (1070071808, "aggr1", 1077477376),
  (1070071808, "aggr1", 1077477376), (1070071808, "aggr1", 1077477376))

val (free, used) = list.partition(_._2 == "NA")
val freeSpace = free.foldLeft(0L)(_ + _._1) // uses Long to avoid overflow
val usedSpace = used.foldLeft(0L)(_ + _._1)
```